# П(п)риложение

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, слово "Приложение" пишем с большой или маленькой буквы?
Например: информация есть в Приложении 1 (то есть ссылка на приложение).
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то ни в Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации под ред. Лопатина, ни у Розенталя нет разъяснений относительно специального употреления прописной буквы в случаях, подобных вашему. Специально просмотрела несколько официальных документов с приложениями. В некоторых слово *приложение* в тексте пишется с прописной буквы, в некоторых - со строчной. Я бы написала со строчной. Если у вас есть таблица, вы ведь не пишете: *информация есть в Таблице 1*. Слово *таблица* пишется со строчной. Думаю, такая же картина и со словом *приложение*, например: *информация есть в приложении 1*.